# Whats the best way to make your printer available trough out the VPN?

Tags: windows-server-2008, openvpn, local-area-network, printing

I just set up a box with a couple XEN virtual machines. One of the virtual machines is running Windows Server 2008 and will soon run our openvpn as well. Is there a way to share this (network) printer to all of our computer so we can print stuff from home and when we get to the office its ready to be dealt with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to run the OpenVPNd in tap mode and bridge the interface to the LAN. That way VPN clients work as if they were physically connected to your local LAN and can see the printer easily.

Also this enables you to handle all clients with the same DHCP server, which might come handy too.